# Truffle deployer.deploy() not working

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, truffle

I'm having problems deploying the contract via Trufflem, using Parity as my client, on the Kovan network.

The contract is a slight variation of [this](https://github.com/WeTrustPlatform/token-contracts/blob/develop/contracts/Trustcoin.sol) one. When I ran `$ truffle migrate` using the project starter files, it ran without problems - I've signed the transaction using the Signer in GUI. However, when I try to deploy this contract, the output is

```
ookie@ookie:~/Desktop/contracts/migrations$ truffle deploy
Compiling ./contracts/contract_name.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'development'.

Network up to date.
```

Also, my 2_deploy_contracts.js file looks like this:

```
var Contract = artifacts.require('./contract_name.sol');


module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(contract_name);
};
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

It's worth mentioning that deployment from Parity interface is working flawlessly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved: For some reason, after deleting whole `build/` folder, everything worked as expected (even if I already tried deleting individual files before)...

Works Perfectly because the built json contract avoids it from being deployed in some cases.

Comment: I have the same issue deleting build folder did not resolve it

Answer (score 1):

`truffle migrate --reset` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `2_deploy_contracts.js` file has a mistake in it. You should have this;

```
var ContractObject = artifacts.require('./contract_name.sol');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ContractObject);
};
```

You need to pass the JavaScript object that represents the contract into the deployer, not the name of the contract. The JavaScript deployer is unaware of the name of the contract.

Comment: Yeah, actually I did pass the object, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question. Thanks!